# Is there any API function to query wikipedia api by website url?

Tags: wikipedia-api

I'm trying to implement something similar to query wikipedia like google is doing.
To explain better; for example if we search "youtube.com" in google, google displays some information on the right.

[image]

But couldn't find the right wikipedia API function to get these details. It's important to search for the website url but not for a general topic like "youtube". Because what I need is exactly to get some details about the website but not for the company only.

I've found a couple of API functions but still couldn't find the right one.

This one for example is returning the original wikipedia link.

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=**google.com**&limit=1&format=json

The response is:

["google.com",["GOOGLE.com"],[""],["https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GOOGLE.com"]]

And this one is not exactly returning what I need and also for some other websites it's just returning different results for different websites.

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=xml&list=search&srprop=snippet&srsearch=google.com

[image]

Any suggestion please.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for me is using 2 APIs.
First checking the url exists here;

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=youtube.com&limit=1&namespace=0&format=jsonfm

and if the last node is not empty then;

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&titles=youtube.com&exintro=&exsentences=55&explaintext=&redirects=&formatversion=2

exsentences is key on this function.

Hope it helps someone else.